# set imagename from variable - Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

want to set imageNamed from variable imgname.

```
NSString * imgname = @"hamburger.jpg";

cell.imgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"**Set imgname variable here**"];
```

I want like this: **cell.imgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hamburger.jpg"];**

Comment: your question is not clear, you want to set or get the image name

Comment: imageNamed: method takes NSString as argument which  your imageName actually is. This will do: cell.imgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed: imgname];

Comment: yes but by this method it will be like cell.imgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed: hamburger.jpg]; which is wrong  . . . . I want cell.imgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Hamburger.jpg"];

Comment: whats your question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write the `variable` inside the `@""` , You have to write Down like the following Code -

```
cell.imgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:<#(nonnull NSString *)#>];
```

In place of `<#(nonnull NSString *)#>` you have to pass your `NSString Variable` only.

```
cell.imgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed: imgname];
```